# How to remove 0 from 1.0 and 0.1 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, ecmascript-6, floating-point

These below are my input

```
let str1="1.0";
let str2="0.1";
```

> I am expecting the result would be, **`1.`** and **`.1`**

I have tried these below ways. But Not working.

```js
let str1="1.0";
let str2="0.1";

console.log(str1.replace(/^0+(?!\.|$)/, ''));//1.0
console.log(str2.replace(/^0+(?!\.|$)/, ''));//0.1
console.log(parseFloat(str1).toFixed(0));//1
console.log(parseFloat(str2).toFixed(0));//2
```

Comment: `1.` is not a valid float number in javascript

Comment: Do you want numbers or strings?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Are you sure? `console.log(parseFloat(1.));` given a value to me. \

Comment: @RameshRajendran that should be string type and not number type

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: `1.` is a valid number literal. What do you mean by "not a valid float number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about number format you can just use this simple regex to remove all zeros before or after the decimal point:

```
/^0*|0*$/g
```

```js
console.log("1.0".replace(/^0*|0*$/g, ""));
console.log("0.1".replace(/^0*|0*$/g, ""));

console.log("1.0000".replace(/^0*|0*$/g, ""));
console.log("0.0001".replace(/^0*|0*$/g, ""));
```

You can, as you observed yourself, later just use `parseFloat()` to get the numbers back behind the strings

Comment: It's Enough to me now. but I am not sure, if I want this as a float number?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get you there, in what format do you want the numbers? You of course don't need to use `parseFloat`, just the replacing will give you the desired result

Answer (score 0):

this will remove any zeros:

```
data.replace(/0/g, '');
```

Example:

```js
var data = ["1.0", "0.1", "1.1", "0.0"];
    
for(count = 0; count < data.length; count++){
 filtered = data[count].replace(/0/g, '');
 document.write(filtered + "<br>");
}
```

Result:

```
1.
.1
1.1
.
```

Comment: What about if it not a string

Comment: This will take precision away from numbers like `0.001`